# CppCMS XML parser

Tags: cppcms

Is there an XML parser in CppCMS? The application I'm designing includes accessing multiple web services. In order to develop a web service client, is there a built in WSDL/XML parser, or, do I have to rely on some third party parser? Or, is there a work around/efficient way by using JSON.

By the way, I'm a C/C++ developer, and not a web developer. Please keep in mind before answering.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is [no built-in XML parser so far](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.cppcms.user/1277) and I see no plans to have one in [CppCMS 1.x.x](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tasks)

But it's easy to include and use one. You have to use cppcms::http::request::raw_post_data() and use a third-party parser with it (tinyxml, libxml2.. I prefer rapidxml).

CppCMS has nice support for web services with [JSON-RPC](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_json_rpc) and I recommend to choose this path over soap/wsdl because is lighter, but it depends on what you want to accomplish.